# Rave drum loops like Netsky?

Tags: drums, electronic-music, beats

I want to start making some rave music. I listened to a few songs which seamed to share a nearly identical beat. (listen to Black & Blue - Miike Snow (Netsky Remix) for an example. I've been searching for this drum loop but wasn't able to find anything useful.

Any advice? If such a thing as a premade rave-drum-beat doesent exist, how can i make one myself?

Btw, im using propellerheads Reason if this makes any difference.

Comment: Hi! This site is generally more oriented towards helping people *learn*, as opposed to helping people *find things*.  As such, I would consider orienting your question more towards the "How can I make one myself?" aspect.  You could ask about the characteristics of a rave beat, for example; just a suggestion :)

Comment: Hello, if you're looking for the good ol' classic ravey drum n bass drum samples, there is a great collection at http://www.junglebreaks.co.uk/ . Amen Break is the most popular, but you will surely recognize others there if you are familar with drum and bass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drumloop you hear on the track that you've mentioned is a chopped/edited version of an 'Amen beat'. Find a refill for Reason with a bunch of REX Amenloops and then mess around. It is common to remove the snare drum and the kick drum from the original loop and add your own kick and snare in place. (This is definitely the case in the song you mentioned).

to get the 'speedy-shuffles' from a Amen loop, remove the kicks and snares from the loop and then turn the decay of each slice down to somewhere between 30 - 50 (in Rex loop player, of course). Now if you play this edited loop with your own kick and snare you should have a very snappy, quick and clean beat. You can layer in some hi-hats/cymbals to give the whole loop some gloss afterwards but make sure that they are hi-passed around 800-900hz and is peaking at around 1Khz - 1200 Hz.

KJ Sawka had released a sample pack on loopmasters website which you might find very useful. Sawka makes these loops by recording himself playing live which gives these loops more human and authentic rhythm than sequenced loops.

http://www.loopmasters.com/product/details/208

Answer (score 1):

There's a decent quality open source drum machine called [Hydrogen](http://www.hydrogen-music.org) that will let you prototype beats quickly and easily. You can export loops, I think, and you can also hook it up to play well with other software synths, lIke reason. There's an introductory tutorial at http://www.hydrogen-music.org/hcms/node/7.

Once you have the basics of hydrogen down, just search for " beat tutorial" - there are hundreds out there, and they're all transposable onto whatever drum machine software you use.

Answer (score -1):

Since looking at examples is just another way to learn things, I'm going to suggest looking for Guitar Pro files for the song you're looking for, and similar songs. TuxGuitar is a free program to play them, and you can export the tracks to midi, which can be easily imported in any professional music software.